# How to install python3.8/3.7 on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: software-installation, python, 21.04

I failed again and again installing python3.8 on my ubuntu 21.04

Now it is 'ok' but this error message appears from pip (and import ctypes doesn't work too):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 35, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/_ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: cannot import name 'Union' from partially initialized module '_ctypes' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/_ctypes/__init__.py)
```

Comment: What is the install line exactly, normally if you say install python it will be later version, you may have to choose the 2.7/8 version

Comment: What version do you actually want to install? The title says 2.7/2.8 but the question is actually about installing 3.8. 3.9 is the default Python version in Ubuntu 21.04, already installed, why do you need 3.8 in particular? And 2.7 can be installed just by installing the `python2` package.

Comment: sorry, corrected. I need that version for... requirements...numpy
pyqt5
pillow    -- installs older pillow wich isn't compatible with 3.9!!!
gym     --- requires older pillow
gym-retro  --- requires older pillow @raj

Comment: I looked into python3.8/ctypes/: there was just a __init__.py script!! nothing else
So I copied python3.9/ctypes to python3.8/ctypes: appeared the same, then I copied python3.9/ctypes to python/3.8 ctypes... appeared something else.. But it didn't worked

Comment: Do these packages you want to install that aren't compatible with 3.9 come from default Ubuntu repositories? I think in that case you should file a bug that they aren't compatible and can't be installed properly. I guess the maintainers should provide in such a case a 3.8 package as a dependency.

Comment: Try it with `pyenv` or `update-alternatives`?

Comment: @JohnMee What's that?

Comment: oh @raj no it's from github

Comment: @JohnMee I could use Anaconda... Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the project Conda. Conda is for Python environments. Luckily you can choose the Python version you want to use.
Check out at conda.io!
Once you're in a Python environment, install any package by `conda install PACKAGE`. Official documentation: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/packages.html

To create an environment, use `conda create`
To create a Python 3.8 environment, use the python-variable, an example:
`conda create -n "name" python=3.8 #quotes not required`
Then: `conda use "name" #quotes not required`

Answer (score 1):

Here are to ways to install it, here is how it's done:

=================1=================

first update everything and install following packages

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
```

Next step is do make a temporary directory and download the source code of python

```
$ mkdir ~/tmp
$ cd ~/tmp
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/Python-3.8.1.tgz
```

next is to extract it and configure it

```
$ tar -xvzf Python-3.8.1.tgz
$ cd Python-3.8.1
$ ./configure
```

now install it with

```
sudo make altinstall
```

make sure to have sudo privileges while installing everything

=================2=================

Installing it with a third party PPA repo

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install software-properties-common

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3.8
```

to finally check the version of python, execute this command.

hope that helps